# Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I think recently while doing SH1 SH2 Certificate migration we received the below error for a few VMs from one of our Environments, Attaching the error below can Anyone help me with this

catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 746: unexpected token at 'Error discovering Host information for host [dry3ce2eleb-f1].  Failed with error [JSONObject["environments"] not found.]' at /etc/puppet/environments/common/sip/manifests/params.pp:7 on node dry3ce2eleb-f1.baplc.com

We checked the VMs and script, but it successfull for many machine in same enviornment
So suspecting that issue belongs to VM ?

Also tried below command puppet agent --test --noop --debug

Comment: You've tagged [puppet-enterprise].  If you indeed have a PE subscription with which the affected machines are associated, then you should consider availing yourself of the Puppet, Inc. support services to which that entitles you.

Comment: With that said, a 400-series error *should* indicate that the fault is on the client side, and yes, that's consistent with the other information you've provided.